# Marketo REST API - Update Landing Page Templates - System error 611

Tags: php, rest, marketo

I tried to make use of the PHP sample snippet on (Marketo doc page:) [Update Landing Page Template Content by Id](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/asset-api/update-landing-page-template-content-by-id/) with substituting my REST API URL, client_id, client_secret, and a simple template file. It simply produces **bool(false)** as a result.

When I used a slightly different equivelent, I found that my REST call results in... **object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["requestId"]=> string(16) "e714#153c7bf644f" ["success"]=> bool(false) ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["code"]=> string(3) "611" ["message"]=> string(12) "System error" } } }**

What's up with the mysterious error code 611 - what does it really mean, since "system error" is not helpful enough to know - why is it happening in this case?

Does this REST API to update landing page templates actually still work?

```
<?php
/*
  Some other functions that made use of $lp_template_id are up here
*/

$landingPageTemplate = new UpdateLandingPageTemplateContent();
$landingPageTemplate->id = 1234;
$landingPageTemplate->content = new CURLFile("/path_to_my_template/{$lp_template_id}", "text/html", "content");
print_r($landingPageTemplate->postData());

class UpdateLandingPageTemplateContent{
    private $host = "https://xxx-xxx-xxx.mktorest.com";
    private $clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private $clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public $id;//id of the teplate to update
    public $content; //HTML content of Template, required

    public function postData(){
        $url = $this->host . "/rest/asset/v1/landingPageTemplate/" . $this->id . "/content.json?access_token=" . $this->getToken();
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $requestBody = array("content" => $this->content);
        curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/json','Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
        curl_getinfo($ch);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        return $response;
    }

    private function getToken(){
        $ch = curl_init($this->host . "/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" . $this->clientId . "&client_secret=" . $this->clientSecret);
        curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/json',));
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
        $token = $response->access_token;
        return $token;
    }

}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, the C# snippet works like a charm.

Comment: Could you show what a full request looks like with your client id and secret redacted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a simple programming in providing the path to a file.

```
$landingPageTemplate->content = new CURLFile("/path_to_my_template/{$lp_template_id}", "text/html", "content");
```

was supposed to be

```
$landingPageTemplate->content = new CURLFile("/path_to_my_template/{$landingPageTemplate->id}", "text/html", "content");
```